# VB Function to return records based on a date parameter & date field OR another date field (Visual Studio 2008, Report Builder 3.0, SharePoint Lists)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sharepoint-list

Another question sourced from this tricky environment and my inexperience.  It seems like VB Functions are the only way I can deliver on some of these report requirements.

I have a situation where a user wants to see data in a report as follows:

The general requirement is this: when the report is initialized, no data is shown - the user must put in a parameter.  This is complete.  The parameter is a date parameter - if the date is blank, all items in the list will be returned.  If a date is entered for the parameter, all items of typeA or typeB equal to or greater than the data param must be returned.

More specifically, this is what I am trying to accomplish:
Return all items where typeA_date is not blank and is greater than or equal to the date entered in the parameter **OR** return all items where typeB_date is not blank and is greater than or equal to the date entered in the parameter.

Here is the code I have, but it is returning an error:

```
Function dtComprRtrn(ByVal awardField As String, ByVal suspendField As String, ByVal chkDtField As String) As Boolean
    If chkDtField Is Nothing Then
        Return True
    End If
    Dim awardDate As Date
    Dim suspendDate As Date
    If (IsDate(awardDate)) Then
        chkDtField = Convert.ToDateTime(awardDate)
    ElseIf (IsDate(suspendDate)) Then
        chkDtField = Convert.ToDateTime(suspendDate)
    Else
        Return False
    End If
    If awardDate >= chkDtField Then
        Return True
    Else
        If suspendDate >= chkDtField Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End If
```

The error is this:

> "An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native
>   compiler return value: ‘[BC30289] Statement cannot appear within a
>   method body. End of method assumed"

I don't have much experience in this area, or in integrating a function into Report Builder, and I am eternally grateful for any assistance that may be provided.  Thank you much!

Comment: At first blush your code looks fine - the error could just mean that there is a Sub or Function which isn't being closed off properly...Sorry for the silly question but I noticed in the code you posted there is no `End Function` statement - was it just not copied in?

Comment: nkvu, thanks for responding - yes you are right, I missed copying the `End Function` - but this was the answer I hope.  I missed it here AND I missed copying/pasting `End Function` in the custom code for the report.  I fixed this, ran the report and it didn't break.  I won't know if it works until I put it in production though - in my test environment, the data criteria I am filtering for of course does not exist and I don't have permissions to add it (sigh...I know, I know...) Will update Stack once I have actuals.

Comment: Also, further details for this issue:  In the Report Builder layer, the Dataset is called "AB" - on that data set, I have a filter (via the Filter Designer) to call this code.  The expression is:  `=code.dtComprRtrn(Parameters!startDate.Value, Fields!Award_Date.Value, Fields!Suspended_Date.Value)`  It is a Boolean type, the Operator is "=" and the Value is:  `=True`  The Parameter is defined as:  `@startDate`

Comment: Hi there, so is the issue now that the report runs but it does not display the correct results?

Comment: @nkvu - Yes that is correct.  My boss pointed out to me several problems.  One issue was that the input parameters (from the Report Builder filter) - `=code.dtComprRtrn(Parameters!startDate.Value, Fields!Suspended_Date.Value, Fields!Award_Date.Value)` to the actual function were in a different order thank what the function was attempting: `Function dtComprRtrn(ByVal awardField As String, ByVal suspendField As String, ByVal chkDtField As String) As Boolean`

Comment: @nkvu - thank you for working with me on this - it is very much appreciated.  I am posting the solutionin just a minute.

Comment: One I have seen is that you use `awardDate` and `suspendDate` but their values don't seem to be initialised anywhere. Also `IsDate(awardDate)` should always be `True` since you've declared `awardDate` as a `Date`

Comment: @nkvu - Indeed, that also was a problem.  This has been quite a learning experience for me!

Comment: Glad it's sorted :-) Always good when there is a positive outcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code solution that was implemented and appears to be working:

```
Function dtComprRtrn(ByVal awardField As String, ByVal suspendField As String, ByVal chkDtField As String) As Boolean
    If chkDtField Is Nothing Then
        Return True
    End If
    Dim compareDate As Date = DateTime.MinValue
    Dim chkDtDate As Date = DateTime.MinValue
    ' Check to see if input string chkDtField is a date
    If (IsDate(chkDtField)) Then
        chkDtDate = Convert.ToDateTime(chkDtField)
    End If
    ' Check to see if either awardField or suspendField is a date
    ' if not then return false
    If (IsDate(awardField)) Then
        compareDate = Convert.ToDateTime(awardField)
    ElseIf (IsDate(suspendField)) Then
        compareDate = Convert.ToDateTime(suspendField)
    Else
        Return False
    End If
    ' Now we know we have a date in compareDate
    ' and we know that chkDtDate is at least DateTime.MinValue
    ' so if chkFtField was blank then this comparison will always
    ' work if we have a valid date for awardField or suspendField
    If compareDate >= chkDtDate Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```